# How to programatically increase the priority of IntentFilter

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, notificationmanager

This is how I am setting the priority of my application intent filter highest.After receiving the intent Extras I abort the broadcast, but the native app is still receiving the sms and notification bar is still showing the message content which is most annoying as I dont want it to show message body. Is there something I am missing??

```
<receiver android:name=".MySmsReceiver" > 
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
            android:priority="999"
             /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

this is my  receiver's `onReceive()` method

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    abortBroadcast();
             ....
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare your receiver in this way :

```
<receiver android:name=".MySmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Instead of :

```
<receiver android:name=".MySmsReceiver" > 
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
            android:priority="999"
             /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Also try to check the following condition before aborting your broadcast :

EDITED :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
          // doBroadcast();
        else
           abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use this condition as mentioned above `if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED))` this will listen only for the specified receiver called `SMS_RECEIVED`.

Comment: I only want to retrieve the data from intent and then abort the broadcast..But what I am doing now with this condition,the native app also get the intent before I abort the broadcast and `notificationbar` is showing the content again..Is there any time interval with the `orderbroadcast` which I need to be take care of??

Comment: @aneelasafdar See the edited solution I have posted. Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: With this condition if extras are not null which would be most of the case, you are not aborting the broadcast..Hence native app would receive the messages..please correct me if I am wrong.Thanks

Comment: you can use the same condition and do `abortBroadcast();` when extras not null means you got the extras with `Intent`.

Comment: going this way database `content://sms/inbox` is not getting updated with the new received messages..
hence neither the native app nor mine one able to get any new incoming message...

Comment: Is required `permission` added in `Manifest file` ?

Comment: I have added permission for `RECEIVE_SMS`..is their any ohter needed?

Comment: see this reference links. hope you find something useful from it. [http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html ] and [http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android ]  .

Comment: @aneelasafdar if my given solution is helpful to somehow then you can accept/vote it.Thanks.